# Can I declare an accesstoken outside the Intenthandler in AlexaSkill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, strava

I am trying to get data from strava api, I was unable to acquire the activities but am now looking into getting the stats using the endpoint. I've gotten the accesstoken from the intent handler but I am unable to put it in the 'options' header without hardcoding it as it . The access token changes everyday so I need to use the variable but I cant declare the accesstoken globally to where the options header ca reach.

```
const ListMyActivityDataHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "IntentRequest" &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) ===
        "ListMyAcitivityDataIntent"
    );
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const accessToken =
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken;
    let outputSpeech = "This is the default message.";

    const Activitiesurl =
      "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/93008019/stats?accessToken=" +
      accessToken;

    await getActivities(Activitiesurl)
      .then((response) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(response);
        outputSpeech = "the data that I want is ";
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${err.message}`);
      });

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(outputSpeech).getResponse();
  },
};

const options = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer <Accesstoken goes here> `,
  },
};

const getActivities = function (url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = url.startsWith("https") ? require("https") : require("http");

    const request = client.get(url, options, (response) => {
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
        reject(new Error("Failed with status code: " + response.statusCode));
      }
      const body = [];
      response.on("data", (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
      response.on("end", () => resolve(body.join("")));
    });
    request.on("error", (err) => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Comment: Ive tried putting the accesstoken in a function and calling the function in 'options' function GenerateAccessToken(accessToken){
    return accessToken;
}

const options =  {
 headers: {
 'Authorization': `Bearer ${GenerateAccessToken.accessToken}`
}
}

Comment: The access token gathered by Alexa cannot be used into strava. You have to implement Account Linking between Strava & Alexa.